# How to edit font size in code section on Ghost

Tags: css, ghost

I'm using Ghost as blogging platform.
I put my code between ``` just like it's one on stackoverlfow.
This works well but the text size of my code is to big.

I know some css but I don't know how or where I can change this size somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Those code blocks are wrapped in an element (most-likely code or pre wrapped in <>) but you can check what element to apply the CSS to by right clicking on it in your browser and selecting 'inspect'. Inspect will let you look at the code and see what kind of html element it is wrapped in.

Ex:
`This is inside code element`

```
This is inside pre element
```

Once you know what element you need to alter you can target it with CSS and add it to your css style files.

```css
pre{
font-size:18px;
color:red;
}

code{
font-size:16px;
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<pre>Sample code using pre</pre>

<code>Sample Code using code</code>
```